# How do I return specific vector elements in c++ elegantly

Tags: c++, vector, std

I am working on a problem in which I must return a type vector. I know the size of the vector will be exactly two. Is there a way I can return my values in vector form without creating a new vector variable and returning that?

I've tried the following method, but it did not work. As well as curly braces and straight braces.

```
vector<int> foo()
{
    return <1,2>;
}
```

Comment: This suggests you tried something randomly, which is a very hard way to learn C++. [Keep a reference on hand at all times](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). Try and create another `std::vector` if that's what you're returning. C++ cannot and will not read your mind.

Comment: You could also consider `std::pair` or `std::tuple` here.

Comment: If I think what you are asking is how to return a vector without creating a variable, then you want `return {element_1, element_2};`

Comment: `return <1,2>` is not valid syntax.    If using C++11 and later `return {1,2}` will work, but it will not work if building for a C++ standard before C++11.   Before C++11, it is not possible to create and initialise a 2-element `std::vector` with only a single statement - you will need to do something like `std::vector<int> temp;  temp.push_back(1); temp.push_back(2); return temp;`   (i.e. create a named vector, set up its elements explicitly, and return it).

Comment: You're returning by value which by definition involves copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use C++11 or higher version, Just write:

```
vector<int> foo()
{
    return {1,2};
}
```

`{1, 2}` will be deduced as an initializer_list, and it won't cause a copy since we have 'Copy elision'. Since it doesn't have a name, which is also called 'Return Value Optimization'.

You can see in:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can return my values in vector form without creating a new vector variable and returning that?

You are already returning **by value** which by definition involves a copy. If you want to avoid the copying you could try returning **by reference**.

---

Now, with C++11 and onwards we should replace the angle brackets `<>` by braces `{}` as shown below:

```
//vvvvvvvvvvv------------------>You're returning by value!
  vector<int> foo()
  {
//---------vvvvv------------->changed <> to {}
    return {1,2};
  }
```

Comment: "Which by definition involves a copy". Well, not quite, right? This particular copy has been a candidate for elision for a while, and since C++17 _must_ be elided.

Comment: @NathanPierson Although there is mandatory copy elision from C++17, it still falls under the category of "copy initialization". Prior to C++17, whether optimisation is performed is up to the compiler. Also, by reading OP's question it seems that he is not using modern c++(from c++11 onwards), so I answered keeping that(c++11/c++14) in mind. Also note that technically In C++17, there is no copy to elide in the first place!